# eclipse c++ debugging google test with spaces in test name on Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, gdb, googletest

I am trying to debug a google test using eclipse (helios) on Linux, when i run a test (without debugging) using --gtest_filter option (example --gtest_filter=Something*) it runs normally.
when i am trying to run the debugger it pop up this error message:

[image]

without specifiying arguments the debugger works normally, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

problem Solved.

Solution:

use:
--gtest_filter=**'Something***' instead of **"Something*"**
in my case the reason was because of the way eclipse pass arguments to gdb, so the command that will run is:

**gdb ./program_name --gtest_filter=Something***

so the * bothers the gdb (maybe think it is paramater for gdb command).